# How to combine conditional formatting in excel/calc when ranges overlap

Tags: excel, format, conditional-statements, calc

I have a worksheet in Libre Ofice Calc (but I guess this question applies to Excel as well) with many conditional formatting rules. Sometimes more then one rule apply to a cell. This is not a problem for me. In  fact, this what I want. Example

rule 1 changes the background color of a cell to green if true. rule 1 applies to range A1:C4.
rule 2 changes the font to bold if true and applies to range B2:D6.

If a cell in the overlapping range meets both rule 1 and 2 it should return bold letters within a green background.

However it seems only one rule can apply at a time. Is there a way to combine them? I know how to combine several rules for one range of cells, but then i have to write so many more rules for so many more sets of ranges.

Answer (score 1):

It works in Excel. I set two conditions to cover the same range and when both were true, the result was green and bold. It works with the conditions in either order.

[image: overlapping conditional formatting]

Comment: thanks, Cee, but this sure does looks different in Calc. I do not have a 'stop if true'-button. It seems to stop by default. And would this work if the ranges are not exactly the same, but overlap each other?

Comment: If it stops by default then that's probably your problem because you don't want it to stop if both conditions can be true. In that case you'll need to setup a new rule that has both conditions and put that rule first. And yes, in Excel, it would work if only part of each range overlapped.